# Date transformation per hour and day, grouping, R

Tags: r, date, twitter, grouping

I am working on a dataset of 1k+ tweets with a date format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss and sentiment score for each one of them between -1 and 1.

My goal is to use them to analyse stock market predictiveness, thus I need to:

a) Group all the tweets in a given workday *n* between previous day stock market closing hour ( *n*-1)  16:00 and todays closing hour (n 15:59); When grouping I do not care anymore about the hour timestamp, the only thing relevant to me is the day, so I could use e.g. Monday's after hours (16:00 onwards) tweeting and Tuesdays intra hours (until 16:00) tweeting as a one score for Tuesday S&P500 closing score.

b) Group all the weekend tweets + Monday tweets (ie. from Friday 16:00 + Saturday + Sunday + Monday until 15:59) as Monday tweets (essentially a) but with extra days to count weekend tweeting in)

c) Subsequently while grouping generate 1) Sum of all sentiment scores for all tweets from given day/weekend and 2) Average of all sentiment scores for all of those tweets alike in 1)

Is there anyone who can help me in any of those subpoints? This work is essentially my biggest hurdle during my master thesis and anyone who can help me with this can expect a package of Dutch Stroopwaffels delivered home from me! :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future checking this thread, I have found the solution to a) and b):

```
t_timeshift = as.POSIXlt(trump_presidency_valid$date)
t_timeshift_final = t_timeshift

for (i in 1:392){
  if (t_timeshift[i]$hour > 17) t_timeshift_final[i]=t_timeshift[i] + 28800
}

trump_presidency_valid$date <- t_timeshift_final

#next I want to move all saturday days by 24hrs effectivelly eliminating saturday tweets

t_satshift_final = as.POSIXlt(t_timeshift_final)
for (i in 1:392){
  if (weekdays(t_timeshift_final[i]) == "Saturday") t_satshift_final[i]=t_timeshift_final[i] + 115200
}

#lastly I want to move all Sunday days by 24hrs effectively making all Saturday and Sunday Tweets count as Monday Tweets

t_sunshift_final = as.POSIXlt(t_satshift_final)
for (i in 1:392){
  if (weekdays(t_satshift_final[i]) == "Sunday") t_sunshift_final[i]=t_satshift_final[i] + 115200
}
weekdays(t_sunshift_final[1:20]) #checkup if the process went well

trump_presidency_valid$date <- t_sunshift_final #save up
```

Essentially I have moved all the tweets after 16:00 by 8 hours making them effectively next day tweets, same with Saturday and then Sunday tweets, moved them by 24hrs. Now if you use weekdays() you will not find any tweets between Friday 16:00 and Sunday 23:59 ; they all got shifted! I hope someone find it useful!